# Transferring DAX formulas from Powerbi to Power Pivot in Excel

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, powerpivot

I currently have this set of codes in Powerbi which is functional. However, I would like to transfer the DAX codes to Excel as a measure for Power Pivot. However, the syntax error kept appearing. Can someone pls assist me with the syntax issue on Excel. How should I format this on Excel DAX?

```
NPV Test 001 =
VAR _selfamily =
if(HASONEVALUE( Family[Family]),VALUES(Family[Family]),0)
VAR _rate =
SWITCH ( _selfamily, "Book", 0.10, "Pen", 0.08 )
VAR _selyear =
if(HASONEVALUE(Year[Year]),VALUES(Year[Year]),0)
VAR _diffyear =
_selyear - SWITCH ( _selfamily, "Book", 2020, "Pen", 2019 )
RETURN
IF (
ISBLANK ( _diffyear )
|| _diffyear < 0,
BLANK (),
DIVIDE ( 1, POWER ( 1 + _rate, _diffyear ), 0 ) * Operating Profit)
```

Comment: Is `Operating Profit` another measure? If so, this looks like it would throw an error in Power BI too without using square brackets.

Comment: Hi, yes operating profit is another measure. This code works fine in powerbi but not in power pivot, any idea why?

Comment: This would definitely throw a syntax error in Power BI as you have it written. Try copying and pasting from your post back into Power BI as a new measure to see.